# fortify complains about resource in try-with-resources block

Tags: fortify, try-with-resources

I have a try-with-resources block that initiates a few auto-closable objects

```
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("some-file), "UTF-8"))) {
         ......
    } catch (IOException e) {
        .....
    }
```

Fortify scan reports this issue

> The function ... in ... sometimes
>   fails to release a system resource allocated by FileInputStream() on
>   line ....

I'm wondering what's wrong with the code above. I thought try-with-resources can handle multiple auto-closable objects. Any ideas what the problem is? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly Fortify complains about things it shouldn't (false positives), but the code above actually can leak the FileInputStream object.  Consider what happens if an exception is thrown by the InputStreamReader constructor. In that case, we've certainly created the FileInputStream, but it will not be cleaned up.

You seem to be under the impression that every object encountered in the expression that implements AutoCloseable will be managed by the try-with-resources statement. However, if you look at the language spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
try ({VariableModifier} R Identifier = Expression ...)
    Block
```

is translated into:

```
{
    final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
    Throwable #primaryExc = null;
...
```

So, only the "final result" of the expression (BufferedReader in your case) is automatically closed. (Normally, composed streams/readers/writers propogate the close operation down the chain, but remember that our premise here is that one of the constructors failed with an exception.)

You can fix the coding problem by declaring separate variables for each element in the chain:

```
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some-file");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            //...
        }
```

More or less this same example is at [Fortify security issue "Unreleased resource stream" for try-with-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289611/fortify-security-issue-unreleased-resource-stream-for-try-with-resource).

Comment: I had the same issue reported in Fortify and the above fix validated it. Thanks!