# Fortify security issue "Unreleased resource stream" for try-with-resource

Tags: java, file-io, fortify, objectinputstream

Fortify security run Noncompliant Code

```
public static A read(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)))) {
        return (A) os.readObject();
    }
}
```

It is saying "Unreleased Resource: Streams" , but it is inside try-with-resource then what can be the issue? please help me.

Comment: Just FYI: If you return a resource  that is declared in a 'try-with-resources' it will be closed at return. Meaning if you return a resource it will be null. Don't believe me? try it.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the issue your tool is worried about is if `GZIPInputStream` or `ObjectInputStream` throws an exception during instantiation, then the `FileInputStream` won't be closed. You can try the following:

```
public static A read(String path) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path);
         GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(fileInput);
         ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(gzipInput)) {
        return (A) objectInput.readObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Kotlin code and as Slaw suggested above solution was to use try with resource analogious in Kotlin which is `use`. Reference https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/try-with-resources